# RFC 2307 vs Identity Management for UNIX

Tags: active-directory, ldap, user-identification

I'm trying to learn about AD schema extensions, and I've encountered those 2.
what exactly is the difference ? are they contained in each other ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

RFC2307 are the standard attributes and classes used generically in LDAP complaint systems.

Identity Management for Unix implies some services and other bits on Active Directory.  I think you also get an MMC extension that shows some of them.

Answer (score 1):

RFC2307(bis) is, at its heart, a schema developed by Sun and others, most notably PADL, in an attempt to use LDAP as a network information service, not to be confused with NIS or NIS+.